# Django, model.FileFieldm upload to dynamicaly generated url and change filename depending on file md5

Tags: python, django

I need to upload file with Django and put it into users directory with name, generated from files content md5 like this:

```
hashlib.md5(open('filename.ext').read()).hexdigest()
```

File model:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    path = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path())
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')

    def get_file_path():
        #get file, calculate users dir(something like settings.UPLOAD_DIR/user_id/),  
        #calculate files md5 and return generated path
```

How to access just uploaded file from `get_file_path()`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should get you started:

```
from django.conf import settings

hash_dir = hashlib.md5(open('filename.ext').read()).hexdigest()

def get_file_path(*args):
    """
        Creates path if does not exists and returns path
        E.g. assign_path_to_folder(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.name, hash_dir)
    """
    path_to_folder = os.path.join(*args)
    if not os.path.exists(path_to_folder):
        os.makedirs(path_to_folder)
    return os.path.join(path_to_folder, '')
```

The following creates a folder if it doesn't exist, and returns the absolute path to the folder (because MEDIA_ROOT is supposed to be an absolute path).

Comment: And how to access just uploaded file from get_file_path()?

Comment: Is this a single file that is always in the same location?

Comment: It always in the same location but I need to access it while it uploading and stores in memory or may be in any temporary directory. In other words I need to calculate md5 of the file is already uploaded to server but not yet saved to any user dir.